# Didn't turn off anti-virus during install, which components to uninstall/reinstall

Tags: installation

I missed the flag to turn off my anti virus until the second flag came up, I then turned it off but too late.  The error read "can't rename subdirectory...", how much do I have to uninstall/reinstall to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What were you installing?

Comment: I don't mean to be inhospitable, but:
- This is the wrong forum for this kind of question. You would do better seeking out a forum specific to the application you are trying to install. 
- You need to be more specific. What are you trying to install?

Comment: I never turn my AV off for stuff like that. Just select "Ignore" on any alert popups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I was installing the SDK for Android and Eclipse.  I didn't try to re-install, thought I might have to uninstall first

Comment: Associate your accounts to regain ownership of your question. It's on your user page - the last tab.

Comment: Accounts tab is empty, no options to associate accounts

Answer (score 0):

Having turned off anti-virus, what options to you get when you rerun the installer?

If there's a "Repair" option, choose that and it (should) reinstall the minimum required.